# How to make a base class when childs can't inherit?

Tags: python, django, design-patterns, database-design, model

I have a fairly simple model in Django, let's say `Book`:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Because the structure and data basically comes from an external API, I have contained it in its own app and I rather not want to modify it.

Now I want to add another source of different books to the project and I'm not really sure what the best solution is here.

Let's say the second model is:

```
class NextBook(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    long_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
```

So the basic fields are there, but have different names. To get the two together, I can probably use another model with a GenericForeignKey:

```
class BaseBook(models.Model):
    book_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    book_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    book_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('book_type', 'book_id')
```

But then I cannot query for all the book as e.g. `BaseBook.objects.all().order_by('created')` wouldn't work. Surely, I could go on and duplicate a datetime field in the base model and then the title and so on, but I think that would be the wrong direction. Also inheritance seems not a choice if I don't want to touch the specific models.

I am looking for some design pattern or something that let's me efficiently 'plug in' more providers and query for all objects, while not making a huge mess of model structure and database queries.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a fundamental contradiction in your question. Do you assume that, for a given book, the `created` reported by different providers will be the same?

If yes, why can’t you make a `created` field on your `BaseBook` and order by that? You can then drop the `creation_date` from your `Book` (or just ignore it, if you don’t want to touch it).

If not, how do you want to order *books* (not provider entries) by `created` in the first place?

Also, what you’re trying to do sounds like a good case for a free-schema database like MongoDB. There, you can embed provider entries directly in your book documents, then order by something like “`created` from the first provider entry for the book”. Thus, you maintain self-contained provider documents without denormalization. You still need `created` to mean the same thing for all providers, though.

Comment: A given book is never represented in two objects. I don't want to relate one Book with NextBook, they are not related to one another. With provider I just mean where the book information comes from.

Comment: @webjunkie: oh, where was I looking?.. I somehow assumed you had a one-to-many relationship there. My bad!